# Flutter cant import `flutter_webrtc.dart`

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is it i cant import ***flutter_webrtc.dart*** ? this is the the documentation i followed https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.2
  flutter_section_table_view: ^1.0.3
  page_transition: ^1.1.7+6
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_webrtc: ^0.5.8
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

The error says

```
C:\Users\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\TossGame\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:flutter_webrtc] C:\Users\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\TossGame\build\flutter_webrtc\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.cloudwebrtc.webrtc" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:flutter_webrtc] C:\Users\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\TossGame\build\flutter_webrtc\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.cloudwebrtc.webrtc" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: @JanviPatel i already upvote it

Comment: thats mine though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `minSdkVersion` to 21. You can find it inside `build.gradle` it will resolve your issue.

Comment: yeah sure you can check your hangout message box.

Answer (score 0):

It need minSdkversion 21 change minSdkVersion=21 in app level build.gradle file